# EnumDisplayDevices does not return inactive displays in windows

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have a setup where I connect multiple monitors to my system through a USB HUB, there are a total of 5 monitors. However one of them turns blank or is inactive

I am trying to detect that inactive monitor using EnumDisplayDevices but unfortunately the API does not return the inactive one, instead it gives me a list of all the active ones.

Any suggestions??

Below is the code that I tried

```
       DISPLAY_DEVICEW adapter = new DISPLAY_DEVICEW();
       adapter.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(adapter);

        uint deviceNum = 0;
        while (EnumDisplayDevicesW(null, deviceNum, ref adapter, 0))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Adapter name: " + adapter.DeviceName);             

            DISPLAY_DEVICEW display = new DISPLAY_DEVICEW();
            display.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(display);

            uint monitorNum = 0;
            while (EnumDisplayDevicesW(adapter.DeviceName, monitorNum, ref display, 0))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Display name: " + display.DeviceName);
                monitorNum++;
            }
            deviceNum++;
            Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------");
        }
```

Comment: Try QueryDisplayConfig with QDC_ALL_PATHS instead https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-querydisplayconfig

Comment: @SimonMourier Lets say i do queryDisplayConfig to get all monitors, is there a way to determine whether the display is turned on or off?? is flag set to 1 means display is active and 0 means turned off??

Comment: `DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_INFO` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-displayconfig_path_info has a `flags` fields which has `DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_ACTIVE` set if it's active.

Comment: "determine whether the display is turned on or off" I suggest you could try to use [RegisterPowerSettingNotification function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerpowersettingnotification) with `GUID_CONSOLE_DISPLAY_STATE`.